# How to do inference over two steps in a graphical model simultaneously?

Tags: probability, bayesian, inference, graphical-model

I have observed data $D$ about a physical object described by $M$. I would like to determine the posterior distribution of $M$ given $D$, or $p(M|D)$. Now I can't infer this directly because unknown correlations in the observations. So I use parameters $\theta$ to smooth out the data $D$, reducing its effective "weight."

So now the problem to determining the posterior probabillity $p(M,\theta|D)$. Thus I need to optimize $M$ at the same time as $\theta$. I *think* the way to express this problem now is with the graphical model $M \rightarrow \theta \rightarrow D$. It seems that there are two linked inference problems:

1. inferring $\theta$ from $D$:

   $$
   p(\theta|D) = \frac{p(D|\theta)p(\theta)}{p(D)}
   $$
2. inferring $M$ from $\theta$:

   $$ 
   p(M|\theta) = \frac{p(\theta|M)p(M)}{p(\theta)}
   $$

How do I do both these inferences at the same time? Is there a simpler way to write an equation for the whole thing? It's really confusing because in (1), $\theta$ is the "model" but in (2) $\theta$ is the "data." Note that I have priors for both $M$ (keeping it physically reasonable) and $\theta$ (reducing its complexity).

**Edit**: My first attempt to solve this is with the "hierarchical Bayes" method:
$$
\begin{align}
p(M,\theta|D) &\propto p(D|M,\theta)p(M,\theta)
\\
& = p(D|M,\theta)p(\theta|M)p(M)
\\
& = p(D|\theta)p(\theta|M)p(M)
\end{align}
$$
Where the last step uses $D\perp M|\theta$ from the graphical model. While this is appealing, there's one thing missing: there should be a place for $p(\theta)$ as well as $p(M)$. That's because I can say something about the uncertainty parameters $\theta$ independent of everything - they should be as simple as possible. Maybe I need a different way to formulate the problem? Perhaps a different graphical model? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What distributions are known exactly other than $p(M)$ and $p(\theta)$?

Comment: We know also $p(D|\Theta)$ and $p(\Theta|M)$. Although I'm not totally sure the difference between $p(\Theta|M)$ and $p(M|\Theta)$ in this case.

Comment: I don't see the issue with using the hierarchical Bayes method here. The marginal distribution of the $\theta$ in this case is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a Factor Graph and use Belief Propagation to get your posterior.
Your Problem reminds me of Compressed Sensing,
there you get the posterior p(x,s|y) {with y=Ax where y is the observed Data x is the Signal and s ist the sparsity pattern}.

http://www2.ece.ohio-state.edu/~schniter/pdf/ciss10_bp.pdf